# Meaning of dummy macro in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I inherited some macro at the very beginning of which settled down the following line:

```
%macro dummy; %mend dummy;
```

This macro has no special invocation anywhere and I do not understand its meaning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is intended to be used in Enterprise Guide and dummy macro definition is inside another (real) macro definition then it may be a hack intended to force syntax highlighting.

For example:

```
%macro real;
    /* Some sas code but without syntax highlighting */
%mend real;
```

But:

```
%macro real;
    /* Some sas code but without sintax highlighting */ 
    %macro dummy; %mend dummy;
    /* Some sas code with syntax highlighting */
%mend real;
```

It seems to be that it is the `%mend` that re-enables the highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

The macro has no "meaning". It is just a declaration of a macro that does not contain any code. Therefore nothing happens when you run it.

It may, however, be an attempt to clear a previously defined macro with the name `dummy` in order to avoid an unintended execution of this.

A more correct way of clearing (or in this case deleting) a macro would be to use (works in SAS 9.3 and later):

```
%SYSMACDELETE dummy;
```

This way, if you were to execute a macro named `dummy`, you would would get an error that such macro does not exist. You would not get this error if you just emptied the content of the macro as in your example.

Comment: If @griboedov is using SAS 9.3 and `%SYSMACDELETE` is already used somewhere in the code, then the dummy macro might be there as a circumvention as detailed in [SAS Problem Note 52641](http://support.sas.com/kb/52/641.html)

Comment: Agree with @soren's analysis, but would suggest removing this null macro definition from any production code.  All the possible justifications noted are really hacks.  Shouldn't be necessary.  Even %SYSMACDELETE dummy should not be needed in production code.